# Access VBA - condition formatting with 2 different xlFormatCondictionTypes

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to do condition formatting while exporting from access to excel. I have to check condition 1(Type:=xlExpression) and condition 2(Type:=xlTextString). If both are true, then highlight the row with any color in excel. Here is my code:

```
With xlSheet
    Set range = .Range("A1:L1")
    Sheets("xyz").Select

     range.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND($I1>=TODAY(),($I1<(TODAY()+30)))"
    rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Focus", TextOperator:=xlContains


        With rng.FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .Color = Any color            
        End With


End With
```

How do I combine above 2 conditions as one condition.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your post is a bit all over the place in certain areas, so my assumptions on the fixes may be a bit off. However, those things you can probably adjust very easily.

As far as combining the conditions, just place another formula inside the `AND` wrapper of current expression.

```
With xlSheet
    Set range = .Range("A1:L1")

    range.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND($I1>=TODAY(),($I1<(TODAY()+30),NOT(ISERROR(FIND(""Focus"",$I1))))"

   With range.FormatConditions(1).Interior
       .Color = Any color            
   End With

End With
```

Comment: Hi Scott, can you help me out in this issue ..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249927/access-link-child-fields-value-automatically-hidden-how-to-unhide-it